# How are the UILabel and UIImageView created such that they are grey in storyboard document outline?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, ios8

Does anyone know how the grey UIView and UIImageView are created in the document outline?

I'm playing around with this [UIPageViewController example](https://github.com/swiftcast/Swift-Example-UIPageViewController) and notice that the UIImageView and UILabel are grey in the storyboard document outline.  When I select them, they are not really physically there in the page content view controller.  When I look at the swift file, the file has the IBOutlet connection wired up.  It seems to me that the UILabel is there but not really there.  What's amazing is when I run the app, everything works.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so because the hidden checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You have designed the view in another size class. Switch to w/any, h/any to make them reappear.